# Processing of *-context.xml and applicationContext.xml files in Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Web MVC as frontend on hibernate with transactions (all annotation driven). I setup web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>wdman</display-name>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>wdman</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wdman</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Disables Servlet Container welcome file handling.
     Needed for compatibility with Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7.0 -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

I don't understand how are options like `<tx:annotation-driven/>` inherited from root context (in this case the one defined applicationContext.xml) to *-servlet.xml context. It doesn't seem to function. I have `component-scan` in both of these files in order to get application working. Is that ok? Aren't the components duplicated?

Could you help or point me out to some concise documentation describing how these context are merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how are options like `<tx:annotation-driven/>` inherited from root context (in this case the one defined `applicationContext.xml`) to `*-servlet.xml` context

They aren't. These settings are local to the context.

> I have `component-scan` in both of these files in order to get application working. Is that ok? Aren't the components duplicated?

If you have identical `component-scan` config in each context, then yes, the components will be duplicated. It's up to you to specify the scan to only instantiate the components that are necessary for each context.

However, the beans defined in `applicationContext.xml` *are* visible to the child context, so you should be able to keep your component-scan in the parent context, and leave it out of the child context. As a rule of thumb, only MVC-specific stuff needs declaring in the servlet context, and those beans can refer to the beans defined in the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to add `component-scan` only to applicationContext.xml - this finds and instantiates all components (including @Controller annotated classes)(tried through jvisualm). But the application doesn't seem to dispatch requests (`The requested resource () is not available.`). If I put everything to *-servlet.xml, it functions. But it's really bad solution, because I want to provide various other frontends.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice finally lead me to clean solution. In `*-servlet.xml` now I have only: `<mvc:annotation-driven/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>`. And in applicationContext.xml there is complementary filter (exclude @Controller).