# Service injection into Controller (Spring MVC)

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I have a Spring web application, I have built it up to the controller stage and I could inject my Daos, into my Services fine. Now when I want to inject my Service into my controller i get an error for dependency with the Dao and further down the sessionFactory. I don't want to inject these again cause this will ultimately lead me to eventually create a data  source but I have my Daos for data access and they already know about sessionFactory. Am I missing something here?

here's the sample code snippets:

My Service:

```
@Service("productService")
@Transactional
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(ProductDao productDao) {
        this.productDao = productDao;
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
@WebServlet(name="controllerServlet", loadOnStartup=/*...*/, urlPatterns={/*...*/})
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    boolean isUserLogedIn = false;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    public void setProductService(ProductService productService){
        this.productService = productService;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvcServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
         org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:            565)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
            root cause

            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating                bean with name 'controllerServlet': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire   field: private com.phumzile.acme.services.ProductService  com.phumzile.acme.client.web.controller.ControllerServlet.productService; nested exception   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of   type [com.phumzile.acme.services.ProductService] found for dependency: expected at least 1   bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.p ostProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
```

Servlet-Context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.phumzile.acme.client" />
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

App-Config:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
<list>
<value>configuration.properties</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
    <context:annotation-config/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.phumzile.acme" />
<import resource="db-config.xml" />
    </beans>
```

DB-CONFIG

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="10800"/>
     <property name="maxIdleTime" value="21600"/>


    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${jdbc.driver.className}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>

        </bean>
      <bean id="sessionFactory"

          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.a
           nnotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        <!-- Entities -->
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.User</value>
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.Person</value>
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.Company</value>
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.Product</value>
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.Game</value>
            <value>com.phumzile.acme.model.Book</value>
        <!-- Entities -->

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.phumzile.acme" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect
      </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
    </beans>
```

CONFIGURATION.PROPERTIES

```
    jdbc.driver.className=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    jdbc.username=root
    jdbc.password=root
    jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: here's the sample code snippets

Comment: I don't see any code snippets...

It's impossible to answer this without some code to look at.

Comment: Can't see the code, answer is going to depend on how you are doing your wiring.

Comment: Let me try editing the question with the code

Comment: You didn't provide enough of the Controller to see how you were wiring that up.  Can you give us the part of the code where you're trying to wire `ProductService` into your Controller?

Also, a stack trace might be nice.

Comment: Can you post your applicationContext.xml and your servlet.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your component scan in your applicationContext.xml is too broad.  You might be double-scanning your Controllers.  Try making it `<context:component-scan base-package="com.phumzile.acme.services,com.phumzile.acme.repository" />`.  (That's assuming your daos are somewhere in the repository package.)

Comment: I have changed my scanner to what you suggested, still get same error. I have a question though... does anyone know what the predecense of the scans is, between the context for the main classes, and the controllers and if theres a way to change it if there is such a way.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512956/processing-of-context-xml-and-applicationcontext-xml-files-in-spring-applicati) has some good information on the precedence of component scans.